# winmm.dll mciSendString и Kaspersky

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api

Решил использовать mciSendString для записи звука, но как только обращаюсь к этой процедуре

```
        mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias "+ Alias, "", 0, 0);
        mciSendString("record " + Alias, "", 0, 0);
```

Kaspersky  блокирует запись а даже без уведомления, как мне программно сообщить ему что моему ПО можно.

Comment: Добавьте каталог с решениями в исключения проактивной защиты антивируса.

Comment: а пример можно увидеть

Comment: Пример чего? Настроек Касперского? [Вы серьезно?](https://www.kaspersky.ru/blog/kaspersky-add-exclusion/14671/)